# Using redirect() after a failed form (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to do a register form with CodeIgniter. My form is somewhere in the middle of my page and it has an anchor attached.

I want the page to load to that anchor in case the sent form failed, so I am using `redirect(myweb#register)` but the form errors are lost in the proccess, when they should be displayed after making the attempt to send this form.

What can I do?

Comment: With quotes it's better no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than redirecting, you should let the page display as usual so your error display, then use something like jQuery ScrollTo to go back to the anchor.

Comment: Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031596/how-to-show-validation-errors-using-redirect-in-codeigniter

Comment: Actually I did, but I can't redirect to index because the form is processed in a different controller. I don't know how to call a controller from another.

Comment: Then that is the real problem. Which page you redirect to is irrelevant.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say with that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing a redirect the one way of keeping the errors is to use flash data: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'message');
redirect(myweb#register);
```